# Alternative to passing the same parameter to each function

Tags: php, parameters

I created a registry pattern for my project, that can instantiate or get an existing reference to any object.

However, now I find myself having to pass `$registry` to pretty much all functions and constructors in the project, since most of them will require to instantiate other classes themselves. This isn't so bad in itself, that is what the registry is supposed to do, but I'd like to retain my functions more 'pure', only requiring parameters that are unique to it.

I could extend classes to a parent that has a `$registry` object, but since we are dealing with PHP and you are limited to extending only one class, this isn't a good solution.

Here's an example to illustrate it better.

```
Class controller {
  __construct($registry,other parameters) { check conditions; addView($registry); }
  addView( viewObject($registry);
}
```

Any ideas to keep the design more elegant, without passing `$registry` all the time?

Comment: If an object needs a registry, then it needs a registry. If you're doing DI (and you should), then you'll have to pass it in somewhere. If your only concern is that you're essentially repeating the same constructor in all those classes... I don't see that as a big problem, really.

Comment: I'm doing DI, and yes my only concern really is that I keep having $registry on most of my function's parameters (be it constructor or not). Was afraid this was a bad idea and then it would be too late to change it later. If this is considered an acceptable way to design the project around, and there are no other alternatives, then this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a $GLOBALS['registry'] for my project.

This is the only global used and allowed on it. While globals are frowned upon because it can introduce bugs and make the code harder to maintain, the fact that you'd need the registry on 99% of the functions kept the project clean from passing the registry to all functions, and it being the only global greatly reduces the risk of misuse.